# What is the orthogonality condition for associate legendre polynomials with different indexes?

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a closed-form expression for:

$$\int_0^\pi  {P_n^m } \left( {\cos \theta } \right)P_k^l \left( {\cos \theta } \right)\,d\theta$$

where $P_n$ and $P_l$ are Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Due to the particular integral, it is worth to express both (powers of) Legendre polynomials in terms of Chebyshev polynomials, then exploit the orthogonality relationships for the second ones: $$\int_{0}^{\pi}T_n(\cos\theta)T_m(\cos\theta)d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{m,n}.$$

Comment: You mean $(P_n(\cos\theta))^m$ don't you? When I see two indices on the $P$ I'd think associated Legendre functions.

Comment: The question may refers to the "associated" Legendre polynomial $P_n^m(x) = (-1)^m (1-x^2)^{m/2} \frac{d^m}{dx^m} P_n(x)$, where $P_n(x)$ is the ordinary Legendre polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

From (simple) Sturm-Liouville considerations, it follows that (x = $cos\theta$)

$$\int_{-1}^1 P_{n_1}^m (x) P_{n_2}^m (x)dx=0$$ if $n_1 \not= n_2$

Thus the associated Legendre polynomials $P_{n_1}^m(x)$ and $P_{n_2}^m(x)$ are orthogonal if $n_1 \not= n_2$.